# Does a recursive definition of a variable make sense at all?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, infinity, divergent-series

Let $A:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n$. I was given the following equation:

$$A=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^{n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(2^n\cdot\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^n=\frac{1}{2}(-1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^n)=\frac{1}{2}(-1+A)$$

My task is to explain that why this can't be true and to find the mistake in the equation. I think that I found the mistake but I am not  quite sure if I found it correctly so maybe someone can look over it.

First, this obviously has to be wrong, because if I solve $A=\frac{1}{2}(-1+A)$ for $A$ I get $A=-1$. But this can't be true, because $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sum_{k=1}^n2^k)=+\infty$.

I now tried to check every step and the single steps (except the last) seem to be correct. With the last step I thought that it might be a problem that we have replaced the sum with $A$ again, because then we get a recursive definition of $A$. And from my point of view it makes no sense to do this because then we can never assign a value to $A$. So my thought wass that a recursive definition of a variable is completly senseless.

On the other hand I thought that this might be a notation problem my teacher wants to draw my attention to. In our class we are using the symbol $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ once for the series and once for the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$. Maybe we can't replace the $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n$ with $A$ because $A$ is the series and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n$ is the limit and not the series.

So now I am not quite sure why exactly the equation given is wrong, so maybe someone here can explain better.

---

This question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4336337/can-i-use-the-distributive-law-to-write-sum-i-0-infty2i-as-1-2-sum-i) is quite similiar, but from my point of view It wouldn't have helped me to solve my problem, because there is not stated that $A\notin\mathbb{R}$ holds and this was the essential point where I started to understand my problem.

Comment: Okay that would make sense. And $A=+\infty$ holds because $A$ converges to $+\infty$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. See also my answer below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use the distributive law to write $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}2^i$ as $1+ 2\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}2^i$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4336337/can-i-use-the-distributive-law-to-write-sum-i-0-infty2i-as-1-2-sum-i)

Comment: @DietrichBurde Not really. I understand the answer here better than the answers in the provided link and I think that I couldn't have solved my problem with only the answers from the provided link. The point where I really understood my problem was that $A\notin\mathbb{R}$ holds here and this is not mentioned in the provided link.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/37327/42969 and the linked-to questions https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/37327 .

Comment: When applied correctly the technique is useful. Do it with $q$ instead of $2$ and you get $A=(-1+A)/q$ and from there $A=1/(1-q)$ *provided that the series converges*. So nothing wrong with $A$ occurring on both sides of the equation.

Comment: (1) The last step is correct, it's not a "recursive definition of A", it's an equation in A, which might or might not be sufficient to define A. (2) What these calculations prove is "If the series converges, then it must converge to -1." Since it obviously doesn't converge to -1, then you can conclude that it does not converge.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The equation $A=\frac{1}{2}(-1+A)$ is correct, but by solving it in that way, you are assuming that $A$ is a real number (which is not). You should solve it in the [extended line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ where the equation has actually three solutions (see how arithmetic operations work [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line#Arithmetic_operations)): $-1$, $+\infty$ and $-\infty$. Since in this case $A>0$ and the series is not indeterminate (i.e. it does converge to an element of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$), then the only acceptable solution is $A=+\infty$.

Consider this other example where the series is indeterminate,
$$A=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n=1-A.$$
The equation $A=1-A$ has a real solution $1/2$ and in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$  we have also $+\infty$ and $-\infty$, but none of them is acceptable because $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n$ should be the limit of $\sum_{n=0}^N(-1)^n$ as $N\to \infty$ which does not exist.

Comment: Okay I understand this, and $A\notin\mathbb{R}$ only holds because $A$ converges to $+\infty$. But if I would take a series which actually converges to a number in $\mathbb{R}$, then $A$ would be in $\mathbb{R}$ and I could solve the equation like a normal equation in $\mathbb{R}$ or?

Comment: Yes, if for some reason you know that $A$ is real you can restrict the solution to $\mathbb{R}$. The sum of series is a limit and you may apply the usual rules of the algebra of limits.

Comment: @DavidKrell I edited a little my answer providing a case where the series is indeterminate.

Comment: In your "other example" shouldn't the last equation be replaced with $-\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n = (-1)^0 - \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n = 1 - A$?

Comment: @DanielSchepler You are perfectly right, thank you so much for pointing out

Answer (score 9):

In order to try to keep things clear, I'm going to say "the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n$" whenever I'm talking about the *series itself* (that is, the mere sequence of terms that we are interested in summing), and I'm going to say merely "$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n$" whenever I'm talking about the value (that is, the limit) of the series.

Technically, the mistake you made was the very first sentence of your question: "Let $A:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n$." If we don't know whether or not the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n$ converges, then we don't know whether or not the expression "$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n$" is a defined expression. Since we don't know whether or not that expression is a defined expression, we can't define $A$ as being equal to it.

However, we can fix this mistake by adding one more sentence at the beginning of what you wrote:

> **Suppose that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n$ converges.** Let $A:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n$. Then
>
> $$A=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^{n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(2^n\cdot\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^n=\frac{1}{2}(-1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^n)=\frac{1}{2}(-1+A).$$
>
> Solving the equation $A=\frac{1}{2}(-1+A)$ for $A$, we find that $A = -1$.

All of this is completely true! Every step in the above is correct. It's a totally valid, sound proof. However, it is not a proof that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n$ converges to $-1$, because it has that "suppose" at the beginning of it. This is merely a proof that *if* the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n$ converges, *then* it converges to -1.

As it happens, the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n$ actually doesn't converge. And there is no contradiction between the statement "if the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n$ converges, then it converges to -1" and the statement "the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n$ does not converge," so we don't have a problem here.

None of this really has anything to do with recursive definitions. The equation $A = \frac12 (-1 + A)$ is not a recursive definition because it's not a definition. If we had tried to *define* $A$ as $\frac12 (-1 + A)$, then that would have been a recursive definition, and that would have been a problem. But we didn't do that; we defined $A$ differently, and then we did some reasoning which led us to the completely normal and valid equation $A = \frac12 (-1 + A)$.

Comment: This made things a lot clearer. One question: You say that "If the series converges, then it converges to $1$." Shouldn't it be $-1$? Because if we solve the equation under the assumption that the series converges, than we get $A=-1$.

Comment: @DavidKrell Yep, my mistake. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I much prefer this answer, as it stays within $\mathbb{R}$ (which is usually the implicit or explicit domain of the problem). Mentioning extended reals is a diversion from the real problem IMO. +1